# How to solve this error? RuntimeError: indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor (cpu)

Tags: python, pytorch, detection, yolov4, yolov7

This is WongKinYiu / PyTorch_YOLOv4 problem. I found many solutions of this problem in YOLOv7, and no solution in YOLOv4. Since, the community here is more active. Thus, I try to ask here also.

[This is the link to WongKinYiu loss.py](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/PyTorch_YOLOv4/blob/master/utils/loss.py)

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/content/PyTorch_YOLOv4/train.py", line 537, in
train(hyp, opt, device, tb_writer, wandb)
File "/content/PyTorch_YOLOv4/train.py", line 288, in train
loss, loss_items = compute_loss(pred, targets.to(device), model) # loss scaled by batch_size
File "/content/PyTorch_YOLOv4/utils/loss.py", line 69, in compute_loss
tcls, tbox, indices, anchors = build_targets(p, targets, model) # targets
File "/content/PyTorch_YOLOv4/utils/loss.py", line 151, in build_targets
a, t = at[j], t.repeat(na, 1, 1)[j] # filter
RuntimeError: indices should be either on cpu or on the same device as the indexed tensor (cpu)
```

Comment: What I can see in this error message is that when you call `compute_loss()` function you explicitly send targets to device (whatever the device is) but when you call `build_targets()` you don't do the same. So this is how they may end up on different devices.

Answer (score 0):

[The Github issue](https://github.com/WongKinYiu/PyTorch_YOLOv4/issues/424) has a solution from [MheadHero](https://github.com/MheadHero):

> I have found a solution.
>
> Modify your loss.py
>
> `add at = at.to(targets.device) above a, t = at[j], t.repeat(na, 1, 1)[j]  # filter`
>
> Then,
>
> uncomment `indices.append((b, a, gj, gi))  # image, anchor, grid indices` and
>
> comment `indices.append((b, a, gj.clamp_(0, gain[3] - 1), gi.clamp_(0, gain[2] - 1)))  # image, anchor, grid indices`